# How can i read a 0xFF in a file with libc++ istream_iterator?

Tags: c++, libstdc++, libc++, istream-iterator

Consider the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  istreambuf_iterator<char> eos;
  istreambuf_iterator<char> iit(cin.rdbuf());
  int i;
  for (i = 0; iit != eos; ++i, ++iit) {
    cout << *iit;
  }
  cout << endl << i << endl;
}
```

And an input file containing the following: "foo\xffbar":

```
$ hexdump testin
0000000 66 6f 6f ff 62 61 72
0000007
```

Now for the test using clang libc++ vs gnu libstdc++:

```
$ make test
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -stdlib=libc++ -o bug-libcc bug.cpp
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -stdlib=libstdc++ -o bug-libstd bug.cpp
./bug-libcc < testin
foo
3
./bug-libstd < testin
foo�bar
7
```

As you can see the libc++ version thinks the 0xff is the end of stream and it stops reading. So this leads to a couple of questions.

1) Is this a bug in libc++ that I should report? My google searches for existing bugs have turned up nothing.

2) Is there a good way to work around this issue?

**EDIT**

The following code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream ifs ("testin", ios::binary);
  istreambuf_iterator<char> eos;
  istreambuf_iterator<char> iit(ifs.rdbuf());
  int i;
  for (i = 0; iit != eos; ++i, ++iit) {
    cout << *iit;
  }
  cout << endl << i << endl;
}
```

Leading me to believe that it is a binary conversion issue, but that doesn't explain why libstdc++ works properly.

**EDIT2**

Using a file without binary works fine too:

```
ifstream ifs ("testin");
```

So there is definitely something fishy going on. It looks like it might be an issue in the implementation of cin though, not the iterator.

Comment: try doing the output as `int(*iit)`, it could also be that cout is in a badstate after outputting 0xff

Comment: @PlasmaHH unlikely; it's outputting `i` with the surrounding `endl`s.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: really, wouldn't that prevent `3` from bein output through `cout` on the last line?

Comment: @PlasmaHH a) I've tried this without using cout in the middle. b) I don't see how messing up cout would cause (iit == eos) to become true which clearly happens. Note the value of i.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is still a bug in libc++ (in addition to the one ecatmur pointed out).  Here is the fix:

```
Index: include/__std_stream
===================================================================
--- include/__std_stream    (revision 176092)
+++ include/__std_stream    (working copy)
@@ -150,7 +150,7 @@
     {
         for (int __i = __nread; __i > 0;)
         {
-            if (ungetc(__extbuf[--__i], __file_) == EOF)
+            if (ungetc(traits_type::to_int_type(__extbuf[--__i]), __file_) == EOF)
                 return traits_type::eof();
         }
     }
```

I will get this checked in asap.  Sorry for the bug.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Fix Committed revision 176822 to the libcxx public svn trunk.  The fix requires a re-compiled dylib even though the fix is in a header.

Comment: This looks like the right answer. I am investigating how I can rebuild my dylib to check it out.

Comment: On OS X you can test out a new libc++.dylib within a shell by doing: export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="<path to newly built libc++.dylib>".  This is much safer than actually replacing /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib.  See http://libcxx.llvm.org for more information.

Comment: I just built from current svn and tried this:
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/vishvananda/libcxx/lib
clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g -stdlib=libc++ -nostdinc++ -I/Users/vishvananda/libcxx/include -L/Users/vishvananda/libcxx/lib -o bug-libcc bug.cpp
I'm getting the same problem. Not sure if there is something wrong with my build. I've tried sticking some random exception throwing nearby in __std_stream and it doesn't look like it is being picked up. Suggestions?

Comment: nvm, I got it. had to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH when running the built file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have found a bug that has already been fixed.  [This commit](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/__std_stream?r1=145407&r2=145624&diff_format=h) (by [@Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant)) contains the following changes:

```
@@ -104,7 +104,7 @@
     int __nread = _VSTD::max(1, __encoding_);
     for (int __i = 0; __i < __nread; ++__i)
     {
-        char __c = getc(__file_);
+        int __c = getc(__file_);
         if (__c == EOF)
             return traits_type::eof();
         __extbuf[__i] = static_cast<char>(__c);
@@ -131,7 +131,7 @@
                 if (__nread == sizeof(__extbuf))
                     return traits_type::eof();
                 {
-                    char __c = getc(__file_);
+                    int __c = getc(__file_);
                     if (__c == EOF)
                         return traits_type::eof();
                     __extbuf[__nread] = static_cast<char>(__c);
```

You'll notice that the older version stored the return value of `getc` into `char`, which is a no-no for the precise reason that it confuses the `char` value `0xff` with the `int` value `EOF` (i.e., `-1`).

The bug applies only to `cin` because the affected methods are on `__stdinbuf`, which is the type libc++ uses to implement `cin` only; `ifstream` e.g. uses `basic_filebuf<char>`.

Check the `libcxx/include/__std_stream` file on your system to see whether it has this bug; if it does, apply the patch and it should fix it.

Comment: I think @HowardHinnant has the correct answer. Trying to verify

Answer (score 1):

The iterator is extracting from the stream.
The stream needs to be opened with `binary` mode to prevent any translations to the original data.

Next, don't use `char`.  The `char` type can be signed, unsigned or not either, depending on the compiler.  I recommend using `uint8_t` when reading binary octets.

Try something like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
using std::uint8_t;
istreambuf_iterator<uint8_t> eos;
```

Comment: So the binary conversion is definitely part of it. Note the edit above using a binary ifstream. It still seems like there is something weird going on in libc++ implementation though.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be binary conversion. See EDIT2 above.